# Local Notification when remote server is unavailable

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, uilocalnotification

I know that iOS only allows a few background-modes, so is it possible to ping a website when the app is in the background, then use a local notification to alert the user that the server is now unavailable?

I'm able to ping the site, but I'm unsure about the background notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While technically possible it isn't really a good idea. This is a mobile device, so there are many reasons why it wouldn't be able to connect to the server, and it also has limited battery life and potentially limits to the amount of network traffic it can use.

What you describe is much better handled by a server with a fast and reliable connection to the net and which uses push notifications to alert users to the outage.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think about the issues you've brought up here.

Answer (score 1):

I am using BackgroundFetch in with a remote server where I update some information for the application or push a local notification if the server is unavailable. It is good to use the available types of refresh rates for BGfetch and not set exact time interval, the app will adapt to the users needs and check the server at appropriate intervals that preserves the battery.

Some good resources: 
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-background-transfer-service--mobile-20595
[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3aperformFetchWithCompletionHandler):